# SSRS : How to make a data set field appear in the footer?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a simple report with a dataset( Patient id, programid, name, address, phone). In my report footer, I am trying to write a condition where the footer value shouldn't show up for specific program ids. But the report footer doesn't display the dataset fields. How do I write this condition for report footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers and Footers can't display fields from your datasets because the dataset is out of scope for the header and footer - it wouldn't know which row to display the field for.

However, you can use aggregate functions to specify a scope and the row and field; for example, to show the ProgramId field from the first row of a dataset, you can use the [First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-first-function?view=sql-server-2017) function, specifying the scope of the dataset:

```
=First(Fields!ProgramId.Value, "MyDataset")
```

So you could do something like this for the Visibility-Hidden property of the footer:

```
=IIF(InStr("10090,116,10094,10083", First(Fields!ProgramId.Value, "MyDataset")) > 0, True, False)
```

Comment: And it's worth noting that an advantage to this approach over referencing a `ReportItems` element is that this will work in the case of multiple pages while the alternative won't if the referenced item is not contained on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The footer and header sections of an SSRS report cannot have dataset items.

You can use the **ReportItems** to refer to a text box that is on your page.

Create a text box on your page with the value that you need then refer to that text box with the expression in your footer.

```
=IIF(ReportItems!TextBox1.Value = 4321, NOTHING, "Your Text Here")
```

[MSDN: Report Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-reportitems-collection-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I created a text box with this expression
=IIf(Fields!ProgramId.Value = "10090"
Or Fields!ProgramId.Value = "116"
Or Fields!ProgramId.Value = "10094"
Or Fields!ProgramId.Value = "10083",True,False)

the expression is for Textbox1

So in Footer, How do I write the expression?

Comment: this is what I am trying to do :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1340c5e4-4214-4204-95c4-abff4a830b22/ssrs-how-to-make-a-data-set-field-appear-in-the-footer?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: To make things easier, change your initial text box expression to make the true and false strings: `,"True", "False")`. Then your text box in the footer would be `=IIF(ReportItems!TextBoxX.Value = "True", NOTHING, "Your Text Here")`. SSRS sometimes has issues dealing with Boolean values that you don't have to worry about with a string. Make sure you update the Text Box value (TextBox**X**) to match the name of your text box.

Answer (score 0):

we can use parameters in footers. you can have a parameter for the specific column and pass the value from code and use the parameter in footer expression like,

```
           =Parameters!Param1.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Page headers and footers can contain static content, but they are more commonly used to display varying content like page numbers or information about the contents of a page. To display variable data that is different on each page, you must use an expression.

If there is only one dataset defined in the report, you can add simple expressions such as [FieldName] to a page header or footer. Drag the field from the Report Data pane dataset field collection or the Built-in Fields collection to the page header or page footer. A text box with the appropriate expression is automatically added for you.

To calculate sums or other aggregates for values on the page, you can use aggregate expressions that specify ReportItems or the name of a dataset. The ReportItems collection is the collection of text boxes on each page after report rendering occurs. The dataset name must exist in the report definition.

For example, to hide or show a logo based on the value of the Customer Type in the dataset, create a Text Box called CustType in the report body, in that Text Box will be your CustomerType field. Then in the header or footer create another Text Box for your aggregate expression like so:
=ReportItems!CustType.Value = "Direct"